# RESEED identity columns on the database

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008, identity-column

Can I use the

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT(<table_name>, RESEED, value)
```

command to reset an identity column current value to the original one in SQL Server 2008?

If yes, is this the correct way of doing this operation without having any drawback?
If not, is there an alternate way of doing this?

Comment: Actually there are three question here. I am sure you can see them... if you need further explanation just ask

Answer (score 8, accepted):

> Can I use the DBCC CHECKIDENT command to reset an identity column current value to the original one in SQL Server 2008?

Yes.

> If yes, is this the correct way of doing this operation without having any drawback?

This is the one documented way of doing it.

Possible drawbacks: you could end up getting duplicate `IDENTITY` values - there's no guarantee from SQL Server that it wouldn't give back a value that's not already in use.

E.g. if your `IDENTITY` currently is 100, and you reset it to 1, chances are sooner or later, it will produce a value that's already in use.

The `IDENTITY` as implemented in SQL Server doesn't check for existing values or anything - it just produces sequential numbers. It's up to you - especially if you did a `RESEED` on that `IDENTITY` to make sure the values aren't duplicated.

Answer (score 10):

The value can be omitted.
So if you use

```
DBCC CHECKIDENT (<table_name>, RESEED);
```

SQL Server sets the ident value to the correct next number - according to the numbers already in use.
This is the only way to reseed identity values I know.

Comment: EG: Setting your identity to start at 2000:
`DBCC CHECKIDENT (<table_name>, RESEED, 2000)`

Answer (score -1):

It has a great drawback if and only if the feild is a primary key and reference to any foreign key in any other table. reseeding helps to fetching of records in transaction table having indexes on the field.

Comment: answer makes no sense.