# Entity Framework SaveChanges Fail increment identity column

Tags: c#, sql-server, entity-framework

I have a question about the Behavior of **Entity Framework** when `SaveChanges` method is executed.

I have an entity that has an **Identity Column**, and just realize that when if I call `SaveChanges` (for a new insert), and it fails then my Identity Column in my DB is increased.

I used to have the Identity column value equals 7, and I was debugging my code and `SaveChanges` method failed 5 times, because I missed to insert a required value, and when it worked out I noticed that my identity column value was now 13.

[image]

Is this a normal behavior? Is there a way to avoid increasing identity column value when Entity Framework fail to do a commit into my DB?

Comment: This is nothing to do with EF, when any insert fails on a table with an identity, it gets incremented anyway, just try it in sql management studio. Why do you care?

Comment: Ok interesting. Is there a way to avoid this behavoir or is something normal?

Comment: I don't think so, its a design feature. Imagine a long transaction started, then another transaction starts, it would be bad if the second one had to wait to see if the first one succeed or not to determine what identity it should use. As I mentioned previously why do you care if your ids are not sequential?

Comment: Thanks Bed, any way I can handle a unique sequential column (I need this to show on reports and the user get confused when the last report had Folio 7 and the next one Folio 13.

Comment: @VAAA You could manually manage a sequential # column, but without a trigger or something similar you'd have the same issue once you delete some rows. Is there something more descriptive you can use to describe each Folio, other than the ID value?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Folio is just a int number and it must be sequential, so I wont allow any gap.

Comment: @VAAA I hope you won't take this the wrong way, but that's a very brittle approach and IMHO it's poor design. Let's say you go ahead with this and at some point you have to update the numbers due to a deletion. So what was "Folio 8" last week is now "Folio 7". Wouldn't that be confusing to the user?

Comment: @BrianDriscoll Totally right, so what do you recommend me to use? a Sequence?

Comment: Don't confuse the Identity of a row with displaying number of rows.  If the ID is 13, then make sure the user can see 13.  If you want to display sequential numbers for the user experience you could use [Row_Number](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms186734.aspx).

Comment: Identity values are for internal use only. Don't connect any business meaning to them. There are case where consecutive numbers are necessary (e.g. invoice numbers). That always requires some hand-written mechanism that's concurrency-proof and transaction-sensitive. Maybe [this question](http://stackoverflow.com/q/20469208/861716) gives some ideas.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This is Sql's behaviour and not Entity Framework.You should have a look at Dbreseed command and execute it for your table if you don't want to Identity to be wasted.check this So question [RESEED identity columns on the database](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4165100/reseed-identity-columns-on-the-database..But) If I were you I wouldn't have bothered.Instead just use Bigint datatype for the identity column